# Groupby sum string

Tags: python, group-by, python-polars

In pandas, I can do

```py
In [33]: df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 1, 2], 'b': ['foo', 'bar', 'foo']})

In [34]: df
Out[34]:
   a    b
0  1  foo
1  1  bar
2  2  foo

In [35]: df.groupby('a')['b'].sum()
Out[35]:
a
1    foobar
2       foo
Name: b, dtype: object
```

and have the strings concatenated when I do `groupby.sum`

In polars, however:

```py
In [36]: df = pl.DataFrame({'a': [1, 1, 2], 'b': ['foo', 'bar', 'foo']})

In [37]: df
Out[37]:
shape: (3, 2)
┌─────┬─────┐
│ a   ┆ b   │
│ --- ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ str │
╞═════╪═════╡
│ 1   ┆ foo │
│ 1   ┆ bar │
│ 2   ┆ foo │
└─────┴─────┘

In [38]: df.groupby('a').agg(pl.col('b').sum())
Out[38]:
shape: (2, 2)
┌─────┬──────┐
│ a   ┆ b    │
│ --- ┆ ---  │
│ i64 ┆ str  │
╞═════╪══════╡
│ 2   ┆ null │
│ 1   ┆ null │
└─────┴──────┘
```

Is there a way to concatenate all the strings in each group in polars?

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way I've found:

```py
In [13]: df.groupby('a', maintain_order=True).agg(pl.col('b')).with_columns(pl.col('b').arr.join(separator=''))
Out[13]:
shape: (2, 2)
┌─────┬────────┐
│ a   ┆ b      │
│ --- ┆ ---    │
│ i64 ┆ str    │
╞═════╪════════╡
│ 1   ┆ foobar │
│ 2   ┆ foo    │
└─────┴────────┘
```

Comment: There's [`.str.concat`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.str.concat.html) e.g. `.agg(pl.col("b").str.concat(""))`

Answer (score 0):

you can use `apply` to do it:

```py
In [18]: df.groupby('a').agg(pl.col('b').apply(lambda subdf: "".join(subdf)))
Out[18]: 
shape: (2, 2)
┌─────┬────────┐
│ a   ┆ b      │
│ --- ┆ ---    │
│ i64 ┆ str    │
╞═════╪════════╡
│ 2   ┆ foo    │
│ 1   ┆ foobar │
└─────┴────────┘
```

Comment: true, but this is kind of slow - best to avoid apply if possible. thanks for your answer anyway!